# why parralax is not working using html css

Tags: html, css, parallax

I've tried a lot to find out what is the problem.
I'm trying to have a `parralax` effect but the parallax effect is not being applied after writing the following code.

I've tired different code around the internet, but nothing is working fine.

Here is the code:

```css
.img1 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="img1">

  <img id="home-section" src="https://i.imgur.com/ROBU0vK.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">

  <div class="ptext">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="home-inner text-center">
        <h2 class="display-4 text-center">DIFFERENT PULSES</h2>
        <br>
        <p> HALUTZIM 26 TEL AVIV<br><br><a href="tel:+972-50-4410600">+972-50-4410600</a></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="arrow">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<section id="studio_mission">

  

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore omnis molestias necessitatibus consectetur velit consequuntur dolorem eaque laboriosam odio, at eius nulla vitae amet est iure reiciendis voluptate ipsam temporibus.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, vel, culpa perferendis amet non delectus dignissimos provident possimus itaque ea eum alias consequuntur veniam modi quos illum! Earum temporibus, odit. Iure temporibus quisquam aut odit amet unde corporis eveniet recusandae ab alias illum veniam mollitia natus accusantium voluptas dolor cupiditate, sed! Distinctio aperiam recusandae dignissimos temporibus, fuga minima assumenda consequuntur dolore asperiores perferendis officia voluptates, neque vero corporis ut quas veniam magni, nesciunt itaque necessitatibus. Obcaecati provident soluta quasi delectus nihil adipisci harum laborum veniam sint saepe perspiciatis sit rem fugiat ut quos, iusto voluptate odio ab vero! Eius minima obcaecati fuga nisi laboriosam totam provident magni cupiditate. Consequuntur mollitia cum ipsum reiciendis ducimus fugit, dolor molestiae animi hic excepturi officia perferendis voluptate accusantium est tempore porro labore quae adipisci, cumque ab asperiores. Nostrum earum sed, minima est, recusandae quam sit quibusdam rem. Aliquid voluptatum laborum iusto quam expedita. Modi at est, aspernatur rerum quae voluptates totam quas, illo iure tempore quia eligendi accusantium natus amet asperiores rem quisquam inventore consectetur, repudiandae veniam earum eum distinctio nobis. Animi dolore nihil quas adipisci reiciendis sed veniam ullam ducimus excepturi. Voluptatem eos quidem distinctio sed maiores ullam! Facere necessitatibus consequatur, dolorum recusandae.
          
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore omnis molestias necessitatibus consectetur velit consequuntur dolorem eaque laboriosam odio, at eius nulla vitae amet est iure reiciendis voluptate ipsam temporibus.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, vel, culpa perferendis amet non delectus dignissimos provident possimus itaque ea eum alias consequuntur veniam modi quos illum! Earum temporibus, odit. Iure temporibus quisquam aut odit amet unde corporis eveniet recusandae ab alias illum veniam mollitia natus accusantium voluptas dolor cupiditate, sed! Distinctio aperiam recusandae dignissimos temporibus, fuga minima assumenda consequuntur dolore asperiores perferendis officia voluptates, neque vero corporis ut quas veniam magni, nesciunt itaque necessitatibus. Obcaecati provident soluta quasi delectus nihil adipisci harum laborum veniam sint saepe perspiciatis sit rem fugiat ut quos, iusto voluptate odio ab vero! Eius minima obcaecati fuga nisi laboriosam totam provident magni cupiditate. Consequuntur mollitia cum ipsum reiciendis ducimus fugit, dolor molestiae animi hic excepturi officia perferendis voluptate accusantium est tempore porro labore quae adipisci, cumque ab asperiores. Nostrum earum sed, minima est, recusandae quam sit quibusdam rem. Aliquid voluptatum laborum iusto quam expedita. Modi at est, aspernatur rerum quae voluptates totam quas, illo iure tempore quia eligendi accusantium natus amet asperiores rem quisquam inventore consectetur, repudiandae veniam earum eum distinctio nobis. Animi dolore nihil quas adipisci reiciendis sed veniam ullam ducimus excepturi. Voluptatem eos quidem distinctio sed maiores ullam! Facere necessitatibus consequatur, dolorum recusandae.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

The problem is the parralax effect is not appearing anywhere, what is wrong with my code ?
Please help 
Thanks

Comment: What parallax effect?

Comment: I've `image` in my HTML , how can I show it here , it is not like uploading image, it is like :
<img src = 'url'> , how can I get to the correct image , as that image is on my computer ? @Martin

Comment: @Martin  please have a look at the updated post, I've added the demo

Comment: @Shikkediel I want to have that , but I'm not getting the right results, is something wrong with my code ?

Comment: check out my solution. I hope you will get your solution @contributor

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better if you set the `background-image` of the div instead of using an `img` inside the div.

```
.img1{

 background-image: url("img/bg-header.jpg");

 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;

 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The way you have it now doesn't make sense. First you must have the `div` with a background image. Below that you can have the `section`.

Comment: When I do that, then I can't see the image @Rob Klein

Comment: Are you sure you have set the background-image correctly in the div?
From your code above it should be 
`background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/ROBU0vK.png")`

Answer (score 1):

check out my code. You need to set the image as background of an div and set a height for it. rest of the thing is fine what you did.

```css
.img1 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/ROBU0vK.png");
  min-height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.ptext {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img1"></div>
<div class="ptext">
  <div class="dark-overlay">
    <div class="home-inner text-center">
      <h2 class="display-4 text-center">DIFFERENT PULSES</h2>
      <br>
      <p> HALUTZIM 26 TEL AVIV<br><br><a href="tel:+972-50-4410600">+972-50-4410600</a></p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm setting the height , but why not when I set the height like : `min-height:100%` then it is not applying ? and When I set in `pixels` , it works fine

Comment: To show a background image you need to put some element into it or set it a fixed height for showing it. It's mainly exception for background image.

Comment: so I can't use `%` for `height` ?

Comment: In this case you can't but if you put a parent div and give that a fix height and img div 100%  at that time that will work. You may check with height 100vh. I am not sure that might work